# Как изменять название гильдии Discord.net c#

Tags: c#, discord

Единственное что напоминает мне хоть сколько-то рабочий код, но это выдает мне ошибку еще до компиляции.

```
private async Task Test(SocketGuild socketguild)
{
    if (socketguild.Id == айди моей гильдии)
    {
        await socketguild.Name.Replace("Старое название", "Новое название");
    }
}
```

Я пробовал делать следующим образом, но даже не смог разобраться как это реализовать, чтобы хотя бы ошибки до компиляции не было.

```
 await socketguild.ModifyAsync();
```

Comment: Там стандартный `Action`, а значит спокойно можно сделать через лямбду все, что хотите (`ModifyAsync(config => {  config.Name = "Новое название"; config.Icon = new("c:/img.png");  })`)

Comment: Проблема в том, что я новичок в программировании и пока не умею пользоваться лямбдами.
Из вашего кода так же я мало что понимаю.
Мне бы просто чтобы оно меняло название сервера, а остальное на подобии смогу сделать если понадобится.

Comment: Новичок - не оправдание, не отключайте голову! Я вам дал дополнение к вашему коду, вставляйте к себе, готово. Чего тут понимать то собрались? Я же вам не псевдо код написал, а реальный код, который можете копипастить.

Comment: Я не оправдываюсь, просто как факт, что не знаю такого приема.
Просто у меня пока бывают сложности со связыванием таких примеров с чем-то конкретным.
После вашего комментария стало намного понятнее и теперь это работает.
Спасибо вам!

Comment: Ну, не знаю, как могут быть сложности со связыванием того, что я дал с тем, что у вас в вопросе, ведь начинаете читать мой комментарий, видите там `ModifyAsync(...)`, в голове сразу "ага, я это где-то уже видел", ищите, видите это и в вопросе, и у себя в коде, вроде логично и просто. Так что, не придумывайте себе лишнего, научитесь анализировать, экспериментировать, ну а также, учитесь читать документацию, ведь если зайти туда, найти нужный объект, посмотреть что он принимает, увидите сразу все нужное, включая [готовый пример](https://discordnet.dev/api/Discord.GuildProperties.html).